# I lose 150 points. Can the system return it back to me?

Tags: discussion

I am sorry that I may ask a question in the wrong place.
But I do not know where to ask my question.
Recently, I set a bounty of 150 points to my question [A problem about SQNR, PCM, DPCM, and DM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/a-problem-about-sqnr-pcm-dpcm-and-dm).
After seven days, no one answer this question.
And then, I lose the 150 points.
Can the system return these 150 points to me?
Thank you very much.

Note: I also want to apologize for my awful English writing ability because English is not my mother language.

Comment: you should go to the meta site and ask about this.  it surely seems unfair that they doc you 150 for any reason.

Comment: @PeterK. might you have any idea what's happened here?

Comment: [Unfortunately not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56298/612423). My suggestion for this network specifically (DSP.SE) is to wait a bit - if there's no comments, it's unlikely you'll get an answer even with bounty. You could try: (1) 50 bounty if 150 is too much to lose; (2) minor edits to the question, which "bump" it (make it show up on top of the page so people see it again), but don't do this too often since it's considered spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't! That's why you get this explicit warning that the bounty cannot be refunded:

[image: No refunds]

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's baked in: the bounty is deducted regardless of whether the question gets a bounty-worthy answer.